# Spark structured streaming - readStream() - reading data from current time to last 10 minutes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am building a spark structured streaming application, where I wanted to read the data from delta tables at a scheduled interval of 10 minutes (Irrespective of whether the new data landed into table or not).

Do we have any options in readStream() through which we can read (Current Time() - 10 mins) data for each batch ?

Say if I set a trigger interval of 10 minutes, I would like to read (Current Time() - 10 mins) data   for each batch. I couldnt find any options to do the same in readStream(). It always reads the delta change from previous batch.

2. Also is it possible to start a streaming job without streaming source ? Something like a dummy delta location or a memory stream which doesnt receive any new data over a period of time ?

It would be great, if I can get some solutions in PySpark.

Comment: By definition- if you trigger every 10 minutes- your batch contains the data accumulated in the last 10 minutes when triggered.

Comment: Is it possible to get customized data instead of reading the delta changes from last read ?

Comment: You can implement something along the lines of the [Quick Example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#a-quick-example)

Allow your job to choose where to load data from. It can be as simple as a flag with an if statement.